# paste in new row when value is met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code that automatically creates a set-up that we use at work. I've gathered all the data in one column, and from there it has to copy the data in rows of 12 columns wide and every time he encounters the value 0PBS*RC* it has to start at a new row. what the result now is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrm4r.jpg)

and this is what I want it to be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqClK.jpg)

this is the code I have now:

```
Sub EMCnaarTaq()

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range


Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mix Overzicht")
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Taqman Platen")

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("AI2:AI500")


For Each cel In rng

If cel.Value = "0PBS*RC*" Then
    cel.Copy
  '  Worksheets("Taqman Platen").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8).Select
  '  ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row + 2).Select

    'Worksheets("Taqman Platen").Cells(Offset(2, 0), 8).Select
 '   Sheet2.Cells(Offset(2, 0), ActiveCell.Column).Select
     GoTo Plakken


ElseIf cel.Value >= 1 Then
    cel.Copy

Plakken:

    Dim c
        For Each c In Sheet2.Range("H3:S3,H5:S5,H7:S7,H9:S9,H11:S11,H13:S13")
            If c = "" Then
                c.Select
                c.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False 'Select

               Exit For
            End If


        Next
 Else
 End If

 Next




End Sub
```

I know the problem is that when value 0pbs*RC* is met it goes to a new row, but it just keeps going back to the first blank cell in the range I selected.
I've tried a lot of things and I feel like I'm close but I just can't find that solution.

Regards,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd handle this is to declare a second range to act as the target for pasting the data into, offsetting it one column each time

then when the 0PBSRC value is hit change the target address to the start of the next empty row and continue from there.

something like

```
set SourceRng = Range(AI1:AI500)
Set TargetRng = Range(H3)

for cel in Sourcerng
TargetRng = TargetRange.offset(0,1)
if TargetRng.column  = 20 #column S or cel.value = 0PBSRC
TargetRng = Range("H" & TargetRange.row+2)
 #do copy / paste here

next cel
```

Comment: Thnx for the fast reply, I've tried what you suggested. though i have to say im probably still on newby level i can read vba en understand what you want me to try, but i just can't get it to work somehow... this is what i got now:

Comment: Sorry i can't seem to get the code into the comment... :/

Comment: Can you describe whats happening?

Comment: nothing happens.. it doesn't copy and paste anything at the moment

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Sampson this is the code i got now:

```
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mix Overzicht")
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Taqman Platen")
Set SourceRng = Sheet1.Range("AI2:AI500")
Set TargetRng = Sheet2.Range("H3")

For Each cel In SourceRng
If cel.Value >= 1 Then
TargetRng = TargetRng.Offset(0, 1)
If TargetRng.Column = 20 Or cel.Value = "0PBS*RC*" Then
TargetRng = Range("H" & TargetRng.Row + 2)
cel.Copy
TargetRng.PasteSpecial
End If
End If
Next cel
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, this is what is had become;

```
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim SourceRng As Range
Dim TargetRng As Range


Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mix Overzicht")
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Taqman Platen")
Set SourceRng = Sheet1.Range("AI2:AI500")

Set TargetRng = Sheet2.Range("H1")

For Each cel In SourceRng
If cel.Value = "0PBS*RC*" Then
    Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row + 2).Select
    cel.Copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False 'Select

    ElseIf cel.Value >= 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        If ActiveCell.Column = 20 Then
        Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row + 2).Select
        Else
        End If
    cel.Copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False 'Select
End If
Next cel
```

Thank you for your help!